# How can I execute Taurus junit?

Tags: java, junit5, taurus

> I made a  taurus test spesifcation:

```
execution:

  - executor: junit

    iterations: 5  # loop over test suite for 5 times

    concurrency: 20   # number of virtual users

    ramp-up: 1m       # time of load growing

    steps: 5          # number of steps of growing

    scenario:

      script: src/test



modules:

  junit:

    junit-version: 5

    working-dir: src/main/java
```

> My Unit Test are:

```
package org.steinko.springtutorial;



import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.steinko.springtutorial.Main;



public class MainTest {



    @Test

    void shouldReturnANumber(){

        Main main = new Main();

        String[] arg = new String[1];

        Main.main(arg);

        int  number = main.getNumber();

        assertTrue(0 < number);

        assertTrue(number < 100);





    }



}
```

> My source code place is:

```
package org.steinko.springtutorial;



import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



import org.steinko.springtutorial.NumberGenerator;



public class Main {



    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    private static int number;

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "beans.xml";



    public static void main(String[] args )

    {



        log.info("Guess the number game");

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_LOCATION);

        NumberGenerator numberGenerator = context.getBean("numberGenerator", NumberGenerator.class);

        number = numberGenerator.next();

        log.info("number = {}", number);

        context.close();

    }



    public  int getNumber() {

        log.info("getNumber",number);

        return number;

    }



}
```

> When I run bzt  ./performanctests/unittests.yaml 
>   I get a error:
>
> [2019-03-17 15:34:25,556 ERROR root] Child Process Error: Javac exited
>   with code: 1
>
> /Users/stein/Development/guess-the-number-game/core/src/test/java/org/steinko/springtutorial/MainTest.java:7:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> import org.steinko.springtutorial.Main;
>
> ```
>                              ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class Main
>
> location: package org.steinko.springtutorial
>
> /Users/stein/Development/guess-the-number-game/core/src/test/java/org/steinko/springtutorial/MainTest.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>     Main main = new Main();
>
>     ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class Main
>
> location: class MainTest
>
> /Users/stein/Development/guess-the-number-game/core/src/test/java/org/steinko/springtutorial/MainTest.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>     Main main = new Main();
>
>                     ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class Main
>
> location: class MainTest
>
> /Users/stein/Development/guess-the-number-game/core/src/test/java/org/steinko/springtutorial/MainTest.java:17:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>     Main.main(arg);
>
>     ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   variable Main
>
> location: class MainTest
>
> 4 errors
>
> How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you're trying to use an external dependency in your java class. Taurus doesn't exactly build the module before it tries to compile. So any dependencies that your project has in the classpath would not be recognized. The solution to this is to upload the dependencies as .jar files along with the .java file in the BZ test. Basically, any class/interface that you import in your test script should be supplied as a jar. So your config file would look something like this:

```
  - executor: junit

    iterations: 5  # loop over test suite for 5 times

    concurrency: 20   # number of virtual users

    ramp-up: 1m       # time of load growing

    steps: 5          # number of steps of growing

    scenario:

      script: src/test

      additional-classpath: # just an example - you can include your own .jar files
       - rest-assured-2.9.0.jar
       - log4j-1.2.17.jar
       - groovy-2.4.4.jar
       - rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar
       - json-path-2.9.0.jar

modules:

  junit:

    junit-version: 5

    working-dir: src/main/java
```

More details at https://gettaurus.org/docs/JUnit/